# Is celery the appropriate tech for running long-running processes I simply need to start/stop?

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

My python program isn't the sort of thing you'd create an init script for. It's simply a long-running process which needs to run until I tell it to shut down.

I run multiple instances of the program, each with different cmd-line args. Just FYI, the program acts like a Physics Tutor who chats with my users, and each instance represents a different Physics problem.

My Django app communicates with these processes using Redis pub/sub

I'd like to improve how I start/stop and manage these processes from Django views.  What I don't know is if Celery is the proper technology to do this for me. A lot of the celery docs make it sound like it's for running short-lived asynchronous tasks, such as their 'add()' example task.

Currently my views are doing some awful 'spawn' stuff to start the processes, and I'm keeping track of which processes are running in a completely ad-hoc way utilizing a Redis hash.

My program actually only daemonizes if it pass it a `-d` argument, which I suppose I *wouldn't* pass it if using celery, although it does output to stdout/stderr if I don't pass that option.

All I really need is:

- A way to start/stop my processes
- information on whether start/stop operation succeeded
- information on which of my processes are running

What I don't want is:

- multiple instances of a process with the same configuration running
- need to replace the way I communicate with Django (Redis pub/sub)

Does celery sound like the proper tech for me to use for my process management?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can utilize [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) for this. It is good at running and monitoring long running processes and has an [XML-RPC interface](http://supervisord.org/api.html).

You can view an example of what I did [here](https://bitbucket.org/tebeka/pythonwise/src/tip/update_daemons.py?fileviewer=file-view-default) (example output [here](https://bitbucket.org/tebeka/pythonwise/src/tip/update_daemons.out?fileviewer=file-view-default)).

Comment: This is interesting.  Thanks.  I'll look into it.

Comment: Thanks again.  This looks perfect for what I need.